# Moving MBR on old HDD to new SSD

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, mbr

After running into some problems tonight (that I was able to fix), I discovered that during the Windows 8 installation, the MBR was placed on my HDD (running Windows 7) that was in the system at the time.

Now that Windows 8.1 is my primary OS, I would like the MBR to be on the SSD and I would like to wipe the old HDD so I can use it as a secondary drive.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: [This might help](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/ask_doctor/moving_mbr)